# Batch update manual set of models in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection populated with the following models:

```
rows: [
 id: 1
 category: 'Meetings & Banquets'
 progress: 0.8
,
 id: 2
 category: 'Guest Services'
  progress: '50%'
,
 id: 3
 category: 'Concessionaires'
 progress: '20%'    
,
 id: 4
 category: 'Telecommunications'
 progress: 100
,
 id: 5
 category: 'Restaurant'
 progress: '70%'                                                    
]
```

I would like to batch update two of them like so and have the models which are bound to the view update themselves:

```
rows: [
 id: 1
 category: 'Meetings & Banquets'
 progress: 0.9
,
 id: 2
 category: 'Guest Services'
  progress: '10%'
,
]
```

When I do .add or .reset on the collection it prevents me from adding/updating the model with the same id. What are my options to batch update these models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** with backbone 0.9.9 you can now use the `add` method with the option `{merge: true}`:

> [**add** `collection.add(models, [options])`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add)
>
> If you're adding models to the collection that are already in the collection, they'll be ignored, unless you pass {merge: true}, in which case their attributes will be merged into the corresponding models, firing any appropriate "change" events.

---

i don't believe there is a function that does it for you right now in backbone collections. Maybe you can just create your own?

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyItem,

  update: function(updatedArray) {
    var that = this;
    _.each(updateArray, function(element) {
      if(that.get(element.id)) {
        that.get(element.id).set(element);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

then:

```
var collection = new MyCollection(rows); //creates your collection
collection.update(rows2);  //updates specific models.
```

Comment: This was actually an issue on backbone's github and they've solved it in the master branch, see https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/1752

Comment: Seems like they are still discussing https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/1873 would be cool if they did have all those different update options.